# How to prevent Android Softkeyboard in Capacitor App?

Tags: android, keyboard, capacitor

I am working on a Capacitor app, which will be the only app usable on a device (kiosk mode). The device has a hardware barcode scanner and the web page will have a custom "keyboard" (just some div's) to display only the keys the customer needs.

But every time I tap on an input field, the soft keyboard pops up. I already tried with the "keyboardWillShow" event and to hide it immediately, but it just looks ugly. The keyboard appears for some 100ms, then disappears.

Is there a way to prevent the keyboard in a capacitor app from opening? I do not want to remove the keyboard completely from the android system, because that would prevent the customer for example entering WIFI configuration etc.

Answer (score 1):

Oh how simple is that:

<input inputmode="none" ... />